# Checking Connetion With MONGO DB server with username & Password

Tags: mongodb, authentication, passwords, connection

I wanted to nconnect to the mongo server with username and password here's what worked for me---------

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

# MongoDB connection info
hostname = '10.20.30.40'
port = 27017
username = 'adminUserName'
password = 'secret'
databaseName = 'someDB'

# connect with authentication
client = MongoClient(hostname, port)
db = client[databaseName]
db.authenticate(username, password)
#It will show True if you are authenticated
```

Comment: `authenticate()` is deprecated, and has been for some time. You are actually meant to pass authentication credentials within `MongoClient`, either within the connection URI or within the options block of that function. You also appear to have misunderstood posting on Stack Overflow. You are meant to ask a "question" which receives an answer (or answers). You can ["self-answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) a **question** you pose, but the basic premise is you also ask that **question** and then also submit an **answer**. This is a "this worked for me" post, and answered before.

Comment: Note that it's "okay" to provide another answer to an existing question, just as long as it truly is "another answer". If it just says the same thing as something else already does, then much like questions which have existing answers that already cover them it's probably not desired.